# Contact form in footer, or on contact page for better SEO?

Tags: seo, contact-form

I would like to place the form in the footer of the page, and use the "Contact" link in the main `<nav>` as an anchor to the `<footer>`.

Would this be fine from an SEO perspective, or should I scrap this idea and stick with a straight-up contact page? Or both?

Comment: Do whatever is better for your visitors.

Comment: Of course, but are there any SEO concerns that I should take into consideration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: I have to disagree. The reason being that I was after information as to whether a search engine would be ok locating contact information in the footer rather than a designated page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine from a SEO perspective, but since your form will appear on every page, its content will be ignored when ranking each page. So, you may want to set-up a separate contact page too if you want this to appear in search results.

Comment: "Content" as in a sitemap for example, or was that a mis-type of "Contact"?

Comment: I am referring to the content of your contact form. If you create a separate page, you can add its url to your sitemap too.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer: I was referring to the part where you wrote, "...you may want to set up a separate content page..."